# Iterating over list and appending value to new list

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to iterate over a list, test for a condition, and when the condition is satisfied, to append the matched values to a new blank list. The first time the condition is satisfied, the matched values should append to the new list @ index 0. The second time, to index 1, etc. The problem is, it is appending to the new list at the same index that it was contained in the original list over which I was iterating. If anyone knows how to resolve this, I would be very grateful!

```
for i in range(len(tweets)): #contains list of dictionaries 
    if tweets[i].get('text') is not None:
        string = tweets[i].get('text')
        tweet_text.append(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", string))
```

printing tweet_text displays the following:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [u'easybranches', u'SEO', u'marketing', u'influence', u'social', u'leadership', u'brand', u'branding'], []]
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the condition matches every time, but not the regular expression? Also, you can iterate over a list directly instead of iterating over an iterator from 0 to the length of your list using `for tweet in tweets`.

Comment: `findall` will always return a list. If there is no match, it will return an empty list. So it is doing what you are asking it to do. What did you intend it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` always returns something.  If it finds no matches it returns an empty list.  You are appending an empty list every time your regex does not match.

If you only want to append when a match is found, you need to test on *that* condition:

```
for tweet in tweets: #contains list of dictionaries 
    text = tweet.get('text')
    if text is not None:
        matches = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", text)
        # Test whether any matches were found
        if matches:
            tweet_text.append(matches)
```

You could also collapse the two conditions by using an empty-string default for `get`:

```
for tweet in tweets: #contains list of dictionaries 
    matches = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", tweet.get('text', ''))
    if matches:
        tweet_text.append(matches)
```

Using `get('text', '')` returns an empty string if there is no text; then `findall` will always work, just returning an empty list if no matches are found.

I have also changed your loop.  No need to iterate over the indices; iterate directly over the tweets in `tweets`.

Comment: `strs = [t.get('text') for t in tweets if 'text' in t]', and then using `map` using this list is also possible. Or even something like: `for s in [t.get('text') for t in tweets if 'text' in t]:`